# trying to set and use a password via commandline using ultraVNC on windows server 2003 vnc

Tags: windows, password, windows-registry, vnc

Okay, so I installed ultravnc on windows server 2003.  It uses the ultravnc.i.i file to store password and configuration information.  But I'd like to be able to set the password using the command line.

There is a tool called vncpwd: http://www.sysworksoft.net/products/vncpwd.html

But it's old, and when you use it to change the password, it changes the password in the system registry instead of the ultravnc.ini file.

But, you can set ultravnc to use the registry instead of the ini file.  Success?  No.  I set ultravnc to use the registry (which stores the hashed password that I set using vncpwd), but, it still uses the password in the .ini file.

does anyone know what gives.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this link](http://wpkg.org/Talk:UltraVNC), there's a perl script that generate the password for registry and ini file , once you have generated the password you could put the password in the ini adding some line of code in the perl script ...